# Double bracket list in python

Tags: python

I am having problem understanding double square bracket put next to one another in list. Specifically, on this code below:

```
a = [44,85,123,55,32,34,87][5%7]
```

What is `a` in this context? Is this a 2D array? What does the second bracket `[5%7]` do?

Answer (score 2):

It is a weird way to index, it just means

```
a = [44,85,123,55,32,34,87][5]
```

If you look at the operation

```
5 % 7
```

It means find (5 mod 7), which is 5. From there, it is just an index operation, so it takes element [5] from the list, which would be `34`.

```
>>> a[5]
34
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a list `mylist`, you can access its item via the bracket notation: `mylist[0]` is the first element, `mylist[1]` the second, etc.
A list is often defined using bracket notation too: `mylist = [44,85,123,55,32,34,87]`
To access the sixth element, you can use `mylist[5]` or `mylist[4+1]` or `mylist[5%7]`
And by substituting `mylist` with its value, you get `[44,85,123,55,32,34,87][5]` or `[44,85,123,55,32,34,87][5%7]`.

`a` is set to `34` in this case.